# Last Version of Android-Studio issue

Tags: android-studio

I've Download last version of Android-studio for Mac OS X , but no way to start it, i m getting this error

Symbol not found: _CGContextSetAllowsAcceleration
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_51-b11-457.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libawt.jnilib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices

Edit : 
  posted [Issue #83115](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=83115)

Comment: This sounds like a corrupted installation of Java on your machine.

Comment: i m using Eclipse right now and can start old version of Android Studio without any problem ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Android studio need JDK 1.7 ,

i solved problem, just edit .profile and add this line :

```
export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Change `JVMVersion` Value to 1.7* Of Info.plist  (Path Of Info.plist : /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents).